# AD B2C: Keep Me Sign In cookie expiration time for built in sign in signup flow

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

- What is the expiration time for Keep Me Signed In (KMSI) cookie for the built in Sign/Sign Up user flow in AD B2C?
- Does this functionality works at all on Sign in Sign Up built in AD B2C user flow?
  I've tested the functionality on a built in flow and it doesn't seem to remember me and it's logging me out after couple of minutes. Also can't see any additional cookie being created if the KSMI is checked.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

KMSI is not supported in `all` built-in sign-up sign-in flows.

However it is supported in sign in v1 flow only.